# Unusual flat symbol?

Tags: notation, history, accidentals

Etched onto [Dmitri Shostakovich's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitri_Shostakovich) [gravestone](https://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=953) is his famous ["DSCH" motif](http://dschjournal.com/dsch-motif) in musical notation, but I'm perplexed:  The flat symbol preceding the E5 is not what I know of to be a [flat symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_%28music%29)... What is that?

[image: Zoomed DSCH logo]

Entire image as it appears on Shostakovich's memorial on [findagrave.com](https://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=953):

[image: Shostakovich's grave site]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just a trick of the photograph?  I can sort of see the vertical stroke of the b.   Or perhaps it got knocked off!

Comment: I believe you're right (to _either_ trick of photography or the stem fell off) - according to [another image](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/find-a-grave-prod/photos/2012/338/953_135469088119.jpg) on findagrave.com, the stem is barely noticeable.

Comment: Yes, that picture shows the stem of the flat plainly.
It's a 3-dimensional representation of music, not strict typography.  We must make some allowance for construction and style.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a regular flat. If you look closely the stem still goes up. The stomach of the flat just goes broader than a space. If the lithographer was my student I would make him write that flat again.